# find specific elements in string/list and move them by increment

Tags: python, string, character, increment, move

I try to change the path in an SVG from cm to mm units. The path is defined by the string "d" and looks like this:

```
<path d="M317.3962167,-142.7 L317.3962167,-142.7 ...
```

I now want to move all the decimal points by an increment i (for cm to mm -> i=1). The result should look like:

```
<path d="M3173.962167,-1427 L3173.962167,-1427
```

or

```
<path d="M3173.962167,-1427.0 L3173.962167,-1427.0
```

so if the decimal point is moved and the following list entry is empty either the decimal point should then be erased or a "0" would need to be added. whatever is easier. I assume that first moving all decimal points and then erasing the points which are followed by an empty space in a second loop is the best option.

What I've got so far:

```
def cm_to_mm(chars, char, increment):
# Convert character sequence to list type.
char_list = list(chars)
if "." in chars:
    # Get the current index of the target character.
    old_index = char_list.index(char)
    # Remove the target character from the character list.
    char = char_list.pop(old_index)
    # Insert target character at a new location.
    new_index = old_index + increment
    char_list.insert(new_index, char)
    # Convert character list back to str type and return.
return ''.join(char_list)
```

But this moves only the first occurance of "."

I checked a lot of posts already but most are only talking about moving a character to the end with "append", which is not helping in my case.
Thanks for your help, it's really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex. You can save to manage string positions.

```
import re

def rpl(mo): 
    v= float(mo[0])*10 
    return str(v) 

s= '<path d="M317.3962167,-142.7 L317.3962167,-142.7" >'

re.sub(r"[-]?\d+[\.]?\d*",rpl,s)  

'<path d="M3173.962167,-1427.0 L3173.962167,-1427.0" >'
```

In re.sub the `r"[-]?\d+[\.]?\d*"` is the pattern of the float, `rpl` is a routin with match object as argument, `m[0]` is the first match, i.e. the float.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be a better approach to create a list like this?

```
path_list = [ 317.3962167, -142.7]
new_path_list = []

for i in path_list:
    new_path_list.append(i*10)
```

Now you will get a list with those numbers moved to 1 decimal place. Then you can make your path like this

```
path_string = "M" + str(new_path_list[0]) + ", " + str(new_path_list[1]) + ", L" + str(new_path_list[0]) + ", " + str(new_path_list[1])
```

That would give you a string like you're after wouldn't it?

Comment: the idea is not bad, but no, this would not work. the amount of numbers behind M&L etc are not always the same and also the numbers of M&Ls aren't. Furthermore I also thought of extracting the numbers, multiplying them and then re-inserting them by string.replace but the same number could be there multiple times. might create errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re

input = '<path d="M317.3962167,-142.7 L317.3962167,-142.7"></path>'

# extract all the values inside the tag
values = re.search('d="(.*)"', input)

parsed_values = []
for value in values.group(1).split(","):

    tmp = []
    for v in value.split():
        search_ = re.search("([\w|-])(\d+.\d+)", v)

        # 317.3962167 * 10 -> 3173.962167 
        prefix, num = search_.group(1), float(search_.group(2)) * 10
        tmp.append(prefix + str(num))

    parsed_values.append(" ".join(tmp))

print('<path d="%s"></path>' % ",".join(parsed_values))
```

**Output**

```
<path d="M3173.962167,-1427.0 L3173.962167,-1427.0"></path>
```